# How to remove string after last dash (but skip dashes between some text or if there isn't special formatting text)?

Tags: php, regex

I have that code:

```
<?php $stringx = get_the_title();
echo preg_replace('/-[^-]*$/', '', $stringx); ?>
```

And this work well, but I would like make it little bit more precisely...

My strings are:

```
Production worker - Eindhoven, Netherlands
Production worker - fish - Eindnhoven, Netherlands
Production worker - fish
Porduction worker - fish - Bunschoten-Spakenburg, Netherlands
```

And this always cut a string after last dash....

```
Production worker
Production worker - fish
Production worker
Porduction worker - fish - Bunschoten
```

So I get wrong strings....

But I would like get:

```
Production worker
Production worker - fish
Production worker - fish
Porduction worker - fish
```

So if:

- string contain:

[...]DASH[...] and [a-z],[space]A-Z

[*then cut after last dash*]

elseif:

- last dash is between some text e.g. word-word *[then cut after second dash]*

**But do not cut if text after last dash if text doesn't contain:**

```
- (sometext) a-z,[space]A-Z
```

I hope it is creal... I tried do matching regex, but I can not handle with it. I do not get the regex and mix it with HTML.

Comment: a good site to test your regex : https://www.regextester.com/

Comment: Thank your for this link. I use [link](https://regex101.com/), but really I do not know how to mix them... I never can get what I need... :/

Comment: imho there's too much if then else going on for a one-line regex. I'd first split (in php) by ` - ` and work with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tests = [
    'Production worker - Eindhoven, Netherlands',
    'Production worker - fish - Eindnhoven, Netherlands',
    'Production worker - fish',
    'Porduction worker - fish - Bunschoten-Spakenburg, Netherlands ',
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    $res = preg_replace('/^.+\K-\h+[A-Z].*$/', '', $test);
    echo $res,"\n";
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
    .+      : 1 or more any character but newline, greedy
    \K      : forget all we have seen untill this positin
    -       : a dash
    \h+     : 1 or more horizontal spaces
    [A-Z]   : an uppercase
    .*      : 0 or more any character but newline
$           : end of line
```

**Output:**

```
Production worker 
Production worker - fish 
Production worker - fish
Porduction worker - fish
```

Comment: I didn't believe it's possible to do that in a "simple" regex...learned I was wrong.

Comment: It is really clear  for me and it works like I needed, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

As I said, I don't think you can do that in a one-liner regex (@Toto proved I was wrong here..). So I've written a function that does what you need. Only tested with the given input values.

```
<?php
function reduceItem($item) {
    $pieces = explode(" - ", $item);

    // check if last piece fits the pattern "bar, foo"
    $last = $pieces[count($pieces)-1];
                     // this regex can use simplification or refinement
    if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]*, [a-zA-Z]*/', $last, $matches)) {
        // if so, cut the last piece out of the array
        array_splice($pieces, count($pieces)-1);
    }
    // put the string back together
    return implode(" - ", $pieces);
}

// USAGE
// your test data
$list = ["Production worker - Eindhoven, Netherlands",
    "Production worker - fish - Eindnhoven, Netherlands",
    "Production worker - fish",
    "Porduction worker - fish - Bunschoten-Spakenburg, Netherlands"];

foreach($list as $item) {
    $newItem = reduceItem($item);
    echo "<br>$newItem";
}

// Output:
// Production worker
// Production worker - fish
// Production worker - fish
// Porduction worker - fish
```

Or with your variable:

```
<?php $stringx = get_the_title();
echo reduceItem($stringx); ?>
```

Comment: It works well! You are great! Thank you for that! :)

Comment: Dear Jeff,
I found one problem... How can I make that text must here:

`/[a-zA-Z]*, [a-zA-Z]*/`

must match to:

`a, A`

but not for

`a, a` ? Because I have that string: `Orderpicker - packing. loading` and then it cuts me "- packing, loading"

Could you help me with this regax? Of cours I tried... but really I do not get it...

Comment: this regex `/[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*, [a-z]*/` matches `Packing, loading` but _not_ `packing, loading` - is that what you want?

Comment: or the other way round `[a-z]*, [A-Z]{1}[a-z]*` matches `packing, Loading`

Answer (score 0):

I'll test it and give string like you need, if you wan't some explaination don't hesitate to ask us

```
<?php

$stringx = get_the_title();


$exploded = explode('-',$stringx);

$i=0;
$to_return = '';
if( count($exploded) > 1 ){

        while( $i < (count($exploded) - 1) ){

                $to_return .= $exploded[$i].' - ';
                $i++;
        }

        $to_return = rtrim( $to_return,' - ');
}
else
        $to_return = $stringx;

echo $to_return;


?>
```

Comment: Hm, It doesn't cut well string e.g.:

`Orderpicker, completing ordres - Bunschoten-Spakenburg, Netherlands`

This return:
`Orderpicker, completing ordres - Bunschoten`

But I rally thank you for your time what you spend to do it!